# ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:select])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

This works...

```
a = User.select("users.*, 1 as car_id").limit(2)
b = User.select("users.*, 1 as car_id").limit(2)
a.or(b)
>> returns a combined AR Relation
```

However,

```
a = User.select("users.*, 1 as car_id").limit(2)
b =  User.select("users.*, 2 as car_id").limit(2)
a.or(b)
>> ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:select])
```

If I do `a+b`, it combines, but then converts to an `array`, and I would like to keep an AR relation to continue to do queries on.

#### When the select has different values for car_id, it can not union.  I would have thought the same column name would allow the union.

I am creating virtual attribute (car_id) on the model, as each set of records needs car_id defined with a different value.

How do I solve the error and union with virtual attributes?

I want an ActiveRecord Relation, and interesting enough:

```
SELECT users.*, 1 as car_id
FROM users
UNION
SELECT users.*, 2 as car_id
FROM users
```

works fine when running raw sql.

SQL Example:

```
 a.mail_for(:inbox).name
```

=> Mailboxer::Conversation::ActiveRecord_Relation

```
 a.mail_for(:inbox).to_sql

"SELECT DISTINCT mailboxer_conversations.*, '102' as mailer_id, 'Listing' as mailer_type FROM \"mailboxer_conversations\" INNER JOIN \"mailboxer_notifications\" ON \"mailboxer_notifications\".\"conversation_id\" = \"mailboxer_conversations\".\"id\" AND \"mailboxer_notifications\".\"type\" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') INNER JOIN \"mailboxer_receipts\" ON \"mailboxer_receipts\".\"notification_id\" = \"mailboxer_notifications\".\"id\" WHERE \"mailboxer_notifications\".\"type\" = 'Mailboxer::Message' AND \"mailboxer_receipts\".\"receiver_id\" = 102 AND \"mailboxer_receipts\".\"receiver_type\" = 'Listing' AND \"mailboxer_receipts\".\"mailbox_type\" = 'inbox' AND \"mailboxer_receipts\".\"trashed\" = FALSE AND \"mailboxer_receipts\".\"deleted\" = FALSE ORDER BY \"mailboxer_conversations\".\"updated_at\" DESC"
```

So I pass an array of relations to union_scope...

```
 ar= a.mail_for(:inbox)
 br= b.mail_for(:inbox)
 cr= c.mail_for(:inbox)

combined = union_scope([[a,ar],[b, br],[c, cr])

def union_scope(*relation)
      combined = relation.first[1].none
      relation.each do |relation_set|
        mailer = relation_set[0]
        scope = relation_set[1].select("#{relation_set[1].table_name}.*, \'#{mailer.id}\' as mailer_id, \'#{mailer.class.name}\' as mailer_type")        
        combined = combined.or(scope)
      end
      combined
    end
```

Update:

```
def union_scope(*relation)
  combined = relation.first[1].none
  relation.each do |relation_set|
    mailer = relation_set[0]
    scope = relation_set[1].select("#{relation_set[1].table_name}.*, \'#{mailer.id}\' as mailer_id, \'#{mailer.class.name}\' as mailer_type")        
    combined = combined.union(scope)
  end
  conv = ::Mailboxer::Conversation.arel_table
  ::Mailboxer::Conversation.from(conv.create_table_alias(combined, :conversations).to_sql)
end
```

Resulted in this error:

```
Mailboxer::Conversation Load (5.8ms)  SELECT "mailboxer_conversations".* FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT "mailboxer_conversations".* FROM "mailboxer_conversations" INNER JOIN "mailboxer_notifications" ON "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = "mailboxer_conversations"."id" AND "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') INNER JOIN "mailboxer_receipts" ON "mailboxer_receipts"."notification_id" = "mailboxer_notifications"."id" WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" = $1 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_id" = $2 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_type" = $3 AND (1=0) ORDER BY "mailboxer_conversations"."updated_at" DESC UNION SELECT DISTINCT mailboxer_conversations.*, '102' as mailer_id, 'Listing' as mailer_type FROM "mailboxer_conversations" INNER JOIN "mailboxer_notifications" ON "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = "mailboxer_conversations"."id" AND "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') INNER JOIN "mailboxer_receipts" ON "mailboxer_receipts"."notification_id" = "mailboxer_notifications"."id" WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" = $4 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_id" = $5 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_type" = $6 ORDER BY "mailboxer_conversations"."updated_at" DESC ) "conversations"

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION")
LINE 1: ...ER BY "mailboxer_conversations"."updated_at" DESC UNION SELE...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "mailboxer_conversations".* FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT "mailboxer_conversations".* FROM "mailboxer_conversations" INNER JOIN "mailboxer_notifications" ON "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = "mailboxer_conversations"."id" AND "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') INNER JOIN "mailboxer_receipts" ON "mailboxer_receipts"."notification_id" = "mailboxer_notifications"."id" WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" = $1 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_id" = $2 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_type" = $3 AND (1=0) ORDER BY "mailboxer_conversations"."updated_at" DESC UNION SELECT DISTINCT mailboxer_conversations.*, '102' as mailer_id, 'Listing' as mailer_type FROM "mailboxer_conversations" INNER JOIN "mailboxer_notifications" ON "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = "mailboxer_conversations"."id" AND "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') INNER JOIN "mailboxer_receipts" ON "mailboxer_receipts"."notification_id" = "mailboxer_notifications"."id" WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" = $4 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_id" = $5 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_type" = $6 ORDER BY "mailboxer_conversations"."updated_at" DESC ) "conversations"
```

Comment: @engineersmnky, sorry, pasted incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot answer your actual question as to why these are incompatible I can offer a solution akin to your raw SQL example.

You can perform the same operation like so

```
user_table = User.arel_table
a = user_table.project(Arel.star, Arel.sql("1 as car_id")).take(2)
b = user_table.project(Arel.star, Arel.sql("2 as car_id")).take(2)
union = Arel::Nodes::UnionAll.new(a,b)
User.from(Arel::Nodes::As.new(union,user_table))
```

This will result in the following query.

```
SELECT 
  users.* 
FROM 
  ( (SELECT  *, 1 as car_id 
     FROM users  
     ORDER BY 
       users.id ASC 
     LIMIT 2) UNION ALL (
     SELECT  *, 2 as car_id 
     FROM users  
     ORDER BY 
       users.id ASC 
     LIMIT 2)) AS users
```

Since this will still return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` you can still act on this object as you would any other we have simply substituted the normal data source (the users table) with your custom union data source of the same name.

**Update based on extreme revision** and some general assumptions as to what you actually meant to do

```
a= a.mail_for(:inbox)
b= b.mail_for(:inbox)
c= c.mail_for(:inbox)


combined = union_scope(a,b,c)

def union_scope(*relations)
  base = build_scope(*relations.shift)
  combined = relations.reduce(base) do |memo, relation_set|
    Arel::Nodes::UnionAll.new(memo,build_scope(*relation_set))
  end
  union = Arel::Nodes::As.new(combined,::Mailboxer::Conversation.arel_table)
  ::Mailboxer::Conversation.from(union)
end
def build_scope(mailer,relation)
   relation.select(
      "#{relation.table_name}.*, 
      '#{mailer.id}' as mailer_id, 
      '#{mailer.class.name}' as mailer_type"
   ).arel 
end
```

Comment: First, THANK YOU! I simplified my example, but how would you modify this to union two active record relations?  As the sql is a bit more complex then shown.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I updated and would love your feedback.

Comment: @user2012677 I updated as well although your code was a bit hard to follow so I may have made some assumptions

Comment: @engineersmnky, when testing, it works with relation.first[1].none, the issue is more when I have different "1 as car_id" vs "2 as card_id" in the select. I tried your code, got `NameError (undefined local variable or method `relation' for #` not sure I follow everything but trying.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I think it is working now. I am testing it. THANK YOU!

Comment: @engineersmnky, how is base getting included into the union? I see that it is, but don't understand how.

Comment: @user2012677 [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

Comment: @engineersmnky, you were so helpful on this topic, I thought you may know the answer to this one .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016330/left-join-a-active-record-query-relation-to-another-active-record-query. if so, really appreciate the help.

Comment: I got `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))` in `build_scope(*relations.shift)`

Comment: @keineahnung2345 unfortunately I have no idea what your data looks like. For assistance feel free to open a new question based on this implementation and I am sure someone can assist. That being said your error is in reference to the fact that at least one of your objects in `relations` cannot be decomposed into 2 arguments so something like `[[object]]`

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks. That means I have to rewrite `build_scope` for my data?